# Close all open excel files except one

Tags: c#

Good day to all.

I am trying to merge all the sheets of multiple excel files into one excel file. I have successfully did it using below code:

```
string folder = textBox1.Text;
string[] xlsxfiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.xlsx");
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook finalWB = app.Workbooks.Add("");
Excel.Workbook tempWB = app.Workbooks.Add(xlsxfiles);
for (int i = 2; i <= app.Workbooks.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count; j++)
    {
        Excel.Worksheet ws = app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
        ws.Copy(app.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1]);
    }
}
```

However, the workbooks "tempWB" are still open and some of them got their filenames "1" added at the end (e.g.Book1.xlsx becomes Book11.xlsx).

I've already tried:

```
tempWB.Close();
```

but it is not closing the ones with "1" added to their filenames.

Is there a code that I can use to close all open excel files except one (finalWB in my code)?

Thank you in advanced for the ususal help.

Answer (score 0):

I think `app.Workbooks.Close();`  needs to be called at the end to close all the open workbooks is there are any.

Comment: Hi Gowri. Yes app.Worbooks.Close() is working but before that, I would need to saveas first my active workbook. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully closed all excel sheets by Saving As first the active workbook then run

```
app.Workbook.Close()
```

my code looks like below

```
finalWB.SaveAs(excelReportSaveas, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

app.Workbooks.Close();
```

Thank you Gowri for the reply.